# Positional argument given but does not in the code

Tags: python

**I have the following function:**

```
class Bullet:
    ...
    def display():
        pg.draw.circle(screen,blue,(Bullet.x,Bullet.y),2)
```

After that, I call the function in this block of code

```
if clicked:
    if Player.shoot_available:
        #create bullet
        bul=Bullet(Player.x,Player.y,Bullet.speed,Player.rotate)
        #add bullet to the list        
        Player.bullet_list.append(bul)
for bullet in Player.bullet_list:
    bullet.update_movement()
    bullet.display()
```

The purpose is whenever the user clicks and the bullet is available, create a new bullet and add to the list. Check every bullet, update its movement and display it.
The problem is

```
File "e:\Game\main.py", line 129, in shoot
    bullet.display()
TypeError: Bullet.display() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Can someone give me an explaination?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you call a class method you pass the method an argument 'self'. To solve this problem include `self` in the function declaration.
i.e

```py
class Bullet:
    ...
    def display(self):
        pg.draw.circle(screen,blue,(Bullet.x,Bullet.y),2)
```